# How can I tell when pemmican has spoiled?

Tags: safety, food

Following [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGJ4l_vg4YA) I have made [pemmican](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pemmican).  When making the pemmican I used a food processor instead of rocks (because I'm lazy).  I handled it with care, and according to this handbook, this stuff [will last years](http://www.traditionaltx.us/images/PEMMICAN.pdf), but ... I'm not entirely confident that I can toss this in my pack for a week.  How can I tell when it has spoiled?  Does it look wrong, smell wrong...?

Comment: from my experience, after 3-4 days of eating pemmican, it all looks wrong, and tastes wrong, but that has nothing to do with it spoiling. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Lard/fat can last a long time without going bad if stored in a cool dry place, but it can still go rancid. The smell test is usually the easiest way of knowing if things have gone bad.